# Configurable Order to Tabular Data from Customer Loaded Database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-mvc, database-schema, tabular

I've come across an issue that I am having trouble putting an answer to, and am unable to find any definitive guidance.

I am an engineer on an application that is used by many different customers. Each one of these customers have different requirements for their data and each load data into their own specific databases for use by our app (same tables, just different database instances).

As a reference the technologies we use are: Freemarker, Spring MVC, Java 8, In-House DB Layer (similar to hibernate, but built by us long ago), MS Sql Server.

**Example**

Customer 1 loads data X, Y and Z into table Foo on Customer 1's database instance

Customer 2 loads data Q, R and S into table Foo on Customer 2's database instance

This data is displayed on an HTML page in a tabular format, with whatever ordering we decide to pull it out of the database as, lets say alphabetical in this case.

Customer 1

X

Y

Z

Customer 2

Q

R

S

**The Issue**

Customer 1 comes to us and asks us to change the way it displays. They want it to display in the order of Y, X and Z instead of alphabetical. But we do not want to change the way Customer 2 sees the data, because they are fine with the way it is coming out, so we do not want to change the query in our Java code.

**Proposed Solution**

Add a sequence column to the Foo table, giving the power to the customer to define what order the data shows up in since they are the ones who load the data in the first place.

**Question**

Is this the best way to handle this? Is there a configuration way we could do something like this or maybe something in MSSQL that would help?

I feel like adding a column to a table to define display logic is a poor way to solve this issue, but I am at a loss for an alternative.

The requirement is not negotiable, unfortunately, so telling them "tough" is out of the question :)

Thanks for any help, tips or clarification! Not the easiest concept to put into text.

Comment: @OrderColumn + Hibernate Multi-Tenancy?http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: We have an in house database layer that's been in use for years, so sadly anything with Hibernate wouldn't solve this. I'll add that clarification to the technology list above.